# Meaning of braces while doing in-memory authentication

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

While going through [this link](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/security-rest-basic-auth-example/) for Spring REST security, I came across this code:

```
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("admin")
    .password("{noop}password")
    .roles("USER");
```

I checked the tutorial, but I didn't find the meaning of `{noop}` in the password section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the specified password encoder; per e.g. [this release blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format):

> ### Password Storage Format
>
> The general format for a password is:
>
> ```
> {id}encodedPassword
> ```
>
> Such that `id` is an identifier used to look up which
>   `PasswordEncoder` should be used and `encodedPassword` is the original
>   encoded password for the selected `PasswordEncoder`.

`noop` is short for "no operation" and means the password is stored in plain text, so the password is simply `password`. You can see this being used further down the link you posted, where the `Authorization` header is set to `Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=`, which decodes to `admin:password`.

---

For any non-demo usage note that, per [the class documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/NoOpPasswordEncoder.html):

> This PasswordEncoder is not secure. Instead use an adaptive one way
>   function like BCryptPasswordEncoder, Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder, or
>   SCryptPasswordEncoder.

Comment: but after adding the given code, it is asking me to login, and i dont have any username/password

Comment: @sparsh610 the password is `password`. If the `encodedPassword` is `password`, and the encoder is `noop`, it's in plain text. You can actually see this being used in the example where it's set in the `Authorization` header: `YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=` is `admin:password`.